# Running Mathematica in 'SpouseMode'

Tags: equation-solving, machine-learning, neural-networks, arithmetic, topology

In this previous question I looked into a deprecated capability of Mathematica from Version 2.
[Mathematica command that allows it to read my intentions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194384/mathematica-command-that-allows-it-to-read-my-intentions)
Thanks to all for your answers. I note that Mathematica has since added a 'SpouseMode' switch that not only reads my intentions, but randomly tells me to hurry up, and sometimes corrects my spelling by making it worse. However I am unable to see all of the different new functions enabled, if someone could help...

I'll note before posting that this site says, "Your question is ready to publish! Our automated system checked for ways to improve your question and found none."

SpouseMode says otherwise.

Comment: With MM 12.2 it seems to be improved. Spouse mode ++! Thx for the reminder!

Comment: Much as I like the annual questions on April 1, I look forward to the upcoming Brigadoon Day posts. Even better, the responses remain backwardly compatible for centuries.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I discovered the `SmellCheck[ ]` function. Accepts an *Olfactory Information Format* (OIF) file and identifies possible sources along with other metrics.

But it seems buggy, crashed when I called it with my gym socks as the argument.